# Recommendations needed for a low cost dolly in an arc, not a straight line

Tags: filming, video-production

I need to find a low cost dolly setup for a round table shoot.  I'd ideally use a [Wally Dolly](http://www.wallydolly.com.au), but they don't make the tracks in curved sections.  Can anyone recommend dolly setups of a roughly similar cost which will work in this situation?

Comment: I remember seeing a wally style setup with flexible pipes for tracks once. Can't remember where though.